# React app read only error inexplicably only encountered in Netlify deployment

Tags: reactjs

My website (wsb-tracker.com) is inexplicably getting this error when deployed (with Netlify), but not when run locally:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm having a similar issue.